# Check if SVN revisions differs

Tags: bash, svn

How can I check if 2 revisions in SVN differs?
I only want to know if they have the same content or not.

I know you check the diff command. Example

```
svn diff -r 12345:67890 http://subversion.test.com/svn/myapp
```

But this can produce a lot of output.
The return code of diff is always zero, no matter the outcome.

I am using linux /bash

I want to incoorperate this in a form like:

```
svn diff -r 12345:67890 http://subversion.test.com/svn/myapp
if [[ "$?" == "1" ]]; then
    echo "Code is Different"
fi
```

Comment: All commands accept the `--xml` switch, aimed at automated processing.

Comment: If you have an exact match (considering you don't have any blanks), you could use the modified = `svn diff -r 12345:67890 http://subversion.test.com/svn/myapp | wc -l` since the diff should list modified lines. Then use the modified variable for the comparison.

Comment: @Gnqz That looks like a great solution! Thanx. I need to spend some more time in the good old linux commands. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use:

```
mod=`svn diff -r 12345:67890 http://subversion.test.com/svn/myapp | wc -l`
if [[ $mod -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Code is Different"
fi
```

Since the `svn diff` should list difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with telling svn to use an arbitrary diff command, using `svn diff --diff-cmd some-diff-cmd`.

The low-tech solution could be checking out both revisions and running your `/usr/bin/diff -q` on them; that will yield a different exit status for differing and identical files.